# How to return data from jquery callback fnc?

Tags: jquery, callback

i have jquery click callback, and this grab some data from DOM and I need this data use in another click callback

```
$('#test').click(function () {
    var some_var = $(this).attr('title').split('-');
});
```

and in another click I need use it

```
$('#test2').click(function () {
    init(data_from_test);
});
```

How do I return data from one click to another?

Thank you

Comment: Using a global variable?

Answer (score 1):

```
(function() {
    var some_var;
    $('#test').click(function () {
        some_var = $(this).attr('title').split('-');
    });

    $('#test2').click(function () {
        if( some_var) init(some_var);
    });

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the data in a variable that is accessible to both the first click and the next click.

I would typically have a namespace, so I'd do

`App.currentClickContext = {}`

then in the first click

`App.currentClickContext.data = xxxx`

then in the second I can access that data

Answer (score 0):

You can save the data in a jQuery [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) object on some element.

```
$('#test').click(function () {
    var some_var = $(this).attr('title').split('-');
    $(document).data("someData",some_var);
});

$('#test2').click(function () {
    init($(document).data("someData"));
});
```

Or you could use a global variable (or a property of one single global variable, or a variable in a higher scope as [Esailija](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11562381/95033) and [jAndy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11562398/95033) mention).

```
var globalData = null;

$('#test').click(function () {
    globalData = $(this).attr('title').split('-');
});

$('#test2').click(function () {
    if(globalData) {
        init(globalData);
    {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a (free) variable in a higher scope. For instance:

```
(function() {
   var some_var;

   $('#test').click(function () {
       var some_var = $(this).attr('title').split('-');
   });

   $('#test2').click(function () {
       init(some_var);
   });
}());
```

There are other ways to workaround this issue, like

- using `datasets` entrys
- using a `namespace object`

Comment: Why aren't you in chat these days ? :( Btw you probably don't want to `init` in case `some_var` is still `undefined`

Comment: @Esailija: the author assumed that the checking takes place within `init()` ;)